# Visualize a 408x408 numpy array as a heatmap

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

Hello I want to visualize the [sandbox](https://www.sandbox.game/en/) game map. I have collected the data from API and now I want to create a heatmap kind of visualization, where the color changes depending on how many times the land's been sold. I'm looking for a Python tool / GUI that will let me visualize a 408x408 numpy array. I've tried the seaborn heatmap, but it doesn't look clean (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQhZg.jpg)), even If I try to set figsize to (200, 200) it's not big enough for my needs. I want to have a visualization on potentially whole screen, where each land is big enough so that I can write something on it (potentially price). Better option would be to have a big map with sliders.

Perhaps it's possible to do what I want using Seaborn's heatmap, but I'm not very familiar with it.

Here's the code I used for visualization:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(408, 408)
x_labels = list(range(-204, 204))
y_labels = list(reversed(range(-204, 204)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(100, 100))
sns.heatmap(arr, square=True, xticklabels=x_labels, yticklabels=y_labels, ax=ax)
ax.tick_params(axis="both", labelsize=40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing such large data with seaborn or Matplotlib will be difficult.

For that, we can use Plotly and the dash python library. So, we can add a slider to view some portion of data at a time.

I have used these two libraries.

```
import plotly.express as px
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#creating data
arr = np.random.rand(408, 408)
x_labels = list(range(-204, 204))
y_labels = list(reversed(range(-204, 204)))

#Converted to dataframe
df_data = pd.DataFrame(arr,index =y_labels, columns = [x_labels] )

app = Dash(__name__)

#How many items to show at a time
show_item_limit = 20

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H4('Range'),
    dcc.Graph(id="graph"),
    html.P("Select range"),
    dcc.Slider(
        min = 0,
        max = 408-show_item_limit, 
        step = show_item_limit,
        value = 0,
        id= 'my-slider'
    ),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph", "figure"), 
    Input("my-slider", "value"))

def filter_heatmap(selected_value):
    # Selected value will be passed from Slider
    df = df_data # replace with your own data source
    #We can filter the data here
    filtered_df = df_data.iloc[selected_value:selected_value+show_item_limit,range(selected_value,selected_value+show_item_limit)]
    #Update using plotly 
    fig = px.imshow(filtered_df,
                text_auto=True, 
                labels=dict(x="X-range", y="y-range"),
                x = filtered_df.columns,
                y = filtered_df.index
                )
    return fig
app.run_server(debug=True)
```

See the output image: [Output from code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5lWR.png)

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply. I've had problems with trying to set up dash on my pc, but I've finally got the time to resolve it. This tool is exactly what I've been looking for, thanks a bunch!